# Return Value From Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, return

Just small question as I cannot find an answer that resolves my problem.

I have an ASP page which sends input to a database and then creates a session. I would like to know how to return a certain value in that session on **another** aspx page.

page1.aspx.cs [creates session]

```
public partial class new_questionnaire : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        OscarSQL c;

            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {  
                c = new OscarSQL();
            } // End Page_Load

            //////    Button Method    //////        
            protected void NewQnrButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // Check if the input fields are empty.
                if (QuestionnaireName.Text == "" || CustomerID.Text == "" || NumberOfQuest.Text == "")
                {
                    Error.Text = "Please enter a name for your questionnaire.";
                }
                // Parse input values to OscarSQL.
                else
                {

                    int testRet = c.InsertQuestionnaire(QuestionnaireName.Text, Int32.Parse(CustomerID.Text), Int32.Parse(NumberOfQuest.Text));
                    Session["Questionnaire"] = testRet;
                    Confirm.Text = "Your questionnaire has been named " + QuestionnaireName.Text;
                    Response.Redirect("~/add_questions.aspx");
                }

            } // End NewQNRButton_Click

        } // End new_questionnaire
```

Page2.aspx.cs [Would like value to be parsed here]

```
namespace OSQARv0._1
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //ReturnQnrName.Text here?

        }
    }
}
```

I would like the value QuestionnaireName.Text from **Page1** to be returned to ReturnQnrName.Text on **Page2**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't put `QuestionnaireName.Text` into Session on Page1, you put an integer. If you need the actual text property, put that into session

```
Session["theText"] = QuestionnaireName.Text;
```

And then you can retrieve it

```
string text = (string)Session["theText"];
```

This reveals something about Session. Objects are stored of type `object`, you need to cast them to their correct types once you retrieve them before use. For example, to retrieve the integer you put into Session, you would write

```
int questionnaire = (int)Session["Questionnaire"];
```

Comment: Thanks, This was the clean solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing

```
Session["Questionnaire"] = testRet;
```

On Page1. On Page2 you can just do:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string questionnaire = Session["Questionnaire"] as  string;
     if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(questionnaire ))
     ReturnQnrName.Text =questionnaire ;

}
```

**Note**
Just realized that you put an int in your session but you seemed to want to store a text in Session and retrieve it. The principle is the same.

Comment: Why not: `string questionnaire = Session["Questionnaire"];`

Comment: @Kakashi Because it's bad practice. The value from `Session["Questionnaire"]` can be removed before you get a chance to assign it. Think about InProcess Session State. Your app pool can be recycled at any time.

Comment: I also tried this method. Thanks.
May use this in future as it has more room for expansion =]

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
 string question = Session["Questionnaire"];

    if(question=="")
    {
        //No Value
    }
else
{
    ReturnQnrName.Text = question;
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use Session["QuestionnaireName"] = QuestionnaireName.Text;

in the second page you can retrive values like below

```
                string QuestionnarireName;
                if (Session["QuestionnaireName"] != null)
                {
                    QuestionnarireName = Session["QuestionnaireName"].ToString();

                }
```

or else you can put in ViewState also.  [Passing data between forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx)