# SQL data not populating in asp webform

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Currently can not get any SQL data to populate the web form. When I run the report in Visual Studio preview mode, the data populates, however when running through my web app it displays nothing.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class topvendors
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            getEntity()
            ' startdate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString
        End If
    End Sub
    Protected Sub getEntity()
        Dim strConnString As String = Session("strconnection") 'ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TrialConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandText = "pGetProjectsByUser"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@employeeid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session("userid")
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@reportid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Request.QueryString("id")
        cmd.Connection = con

        Try
            con.Open()
            Dim dt As New DataTable()
            Dim ds As New DataSet()
            'Dim db As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

            Dim da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(ds)
            'db.Fill(ds)
            division.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            division.DataTextField = "entityname"
            division.DataValueField = "entitycode"
            division.DataBind()
            '  If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 1 Then
            'divisions.Visible = False
            ' communities.DataSource = ds.Tables(1)
            'communities.DataTextField = "Projectname"
            ' communities.DataValueField = "projID"
            ' communities.DataBind()
            ' Else
            ' divisions.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("entityname").ToString
            'division.Visible = False

            ' communities.DataSource = ds.Tables(1)
            'communities.DataTextField = "Projectname"
            'communities.DataValueField = "projID"
            'communities.DataBind()
            'End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        Finally

            con.Close()
            con.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
    Protected Sub submit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles submit.Click
        ' Dim communities As String = Server.UrlEncode(Request.Form("communities"))
        ' Response.Write(communities)
        ' Dim removedays As Integer = Request.Form("removedays")
        'getEntity()
        ' MsgBox(sort.SelectedValue)
        Dim builder As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        builder = New SqlConnectionStringBuilder(Session("strconnection"))

        Dim databasename As String = builder.InitialCatalog
        Dim dataname As String
        If databasename = "G3Live" Then
            dataname = "2fLiveReports"

        Else
            dataname = "2fTestReports"
        End If
        Response.Redirect("http://g3reports.danryanbuilders.com/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%" + dataname + "%2fPurchasing%2flance_tutorial&rs:Format=Excel&rs%3aCommand=Render&entityid=" & division.SelectedValue & "&begindate=" + begindate.Text + "&enddate=" + enddate.Text + "&sort=" + DropdownList1.SelectedValue)

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim builder As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        builder = New SqlConnectionStringBuilder(Session("strconnection"))



        Dim databasename As String = builder.InitialCatalog
        Dim dataname As String
        If databasename = "G3Live" Then
            dataname = "2fLiveReports"

        Else
            dataname = "2fTestReports"
        End If
        Response.Redirect("http://g3reports.danryanbuilders.com/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%" + dataname + "%2fPurchasing%2flance_tutorial&rs:Format=PDF&rs%3aCommand=Render&entityid=" & division.SelectedValue & "&begindate=" + begindate.Text + "&enddate=" + enddate.Text + "&sort=" + DropdownList1.SelectedValue)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: So? Debug everything. Step through the code line by line. See that it takes the correct path through the code. Check your connection strings and your queries etc.

Comment: Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex --> you can safely remove that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note:** You are storing connection string in Session, it is not recommendable. You can do but it is better you should use web.config
>   file to store connection string.
>
> **You can be refer  this:** [Avoid storing connection string in session for different sql schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789560/avoid-storing-connection-string-in-session-for-different-sql-schema)

***For Solution I recommended***

1. You must check the session variable prior to getting the value for the connection string.

> ' Check if session is null

```
If Not (Session("strconnection ") Is Nothing) Then
{
     //
}
```

**When it is Null or Nothing or Empty, try to retrieve the connection string again.**

2. You need to cast session variables into their correct types, before use like

> Session("strconnection")

Replace it by

```
Session("strconnection").toString()
```

And

> Cast Session("userid") and Request.QueryString("id") by the help of
>   Integer.Parse/ Integer.TryParse

you can read this for concept:
[Return Value From Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857042/return-value-from-session)

Comment: I figured it out. After a little digging, the division.datavaluefield was set set incorrectly. Should have been entityid not entitycode. Thanks for everyones responses